# How to improve my code for Newton-Raphson method in C?

Tags: c, numerical-methods

I need help in order to improve my code. This code finds the roots of equation, but when it does not have any root, nothing appears on screen. I need "output" in this way: for instance,
`"input" x^2+x+1=0;`
`"output" There is not root of equation.`
Thank you in advance.

```
        #include <stdio.h>
        #include <conio.h>
        #include <math.h>
        #include <stdlib.h> 

        double F(double x){ 
              return asin(x)-M_PI/6;
        }


        #define Tk (double)0.0000001 
        double Fx(double x,double(*F)(double),double k){ 
              return (double)((F(x+k)-F(x))/k); }

        main()
        {
             double x0=100, x, eps=0.001, ep;
              while(1)
            {  
              x=x0-F(x0)/Fx(x0,F,Tk);
              ep=fabs((x-x0)/x)*100;
              x0=x;
              if(fabs(ep)<eps) break;
              }
              printf("%lf", x0);
              getch();
              }
```

Comment: This might be more appropriate for Computational Science on StackExchange...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Newton-Raphson converges quickly to a solution when:
1) The initial guess is close.
2) A solution exist.

When convergence does not promptly occur, it could be for either of the 2 reasons, even though OP is interested in reason #2.  A 3rd reason exists too due to the finite precision of computers: Oscillation about a `+` answer and a `-` answer where `fabs(ep)<eps` is not fulfilled.  In that case return the average when the two values are close.

2 approaches: Simple or Deep

**Suggest this for OP**
Simple: Limit the number of iterations.  Once N iterations (suggest bit width of `double`) occur, exit the loop with a "solution not found (does not exist or no convergence)."

Deep: In conjunction with N-R, perform a binary search.  Once `f(lo)` is of one sign and `f(hi)` is of the other (for a continuous function) , a solution *must* exist even if not findable via N-R.  Use the better of N-R and binary search to find it.  If opposite sign `f(x)` is not found, declare non-existence/unfind-ability.